# I don't get any output from Reprojection

Tags: qgis, pyqgis

I have recently posted a Reprojection issue. I found the solution, but now I can't get the output: I load the resulting reprojection by code, but first, I look into the folder where I have indicated the path. There isn't any data ( I have tried "C:.." first)
I wonder if somebody could test this in order to confirm that this code works.. I think that I have a problem of system administration.

The code is as follows:

```
import processing
from processing.core.Processing import Processing
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *

Processing.initialize()
Processing.updateAlgsList()

rasterLayer = QgsRasterLayer("G:\..example...\SatImage.tif","MTN50")
print rasterLayer.isValid()
crs = QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem(25830,
       QgsCoordinateReferenceSystem.EpsgCrsId)
rasterLayer.setCrs(crs)
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([rasterLayer])#Loading the first     raster


processing.runalg("gdalogr:warpreproject", rasterLayer, "EPSG: 25830", "EPSG:4326", '0', 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 1, False, 1, False, "extraParam", "G:\..newFolder..\reprojected.tif")
reproject = QgsRasterLayer("G:\..newFolder..\reprojected.tif","ReprojLayer")
QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().addMapLayers([reproject])
```

Comment: 25830 is ETRS89 / UTM zone 30 North. 3722 is a US UTM zone. You've got the wrong output WKID. What ProjCRS are you trying to convert to? Did you want BNG (it's 27700)?

Comment: Hello, I didn't see this comment. I try to reproject to EPSG:4326 now

Answer (score 2):

I suppose backslashes need escaping in Python but forward slashes should work also with Windows nowadays. And you can't warp directly into ECW. Test with gdalwarp shows that:

```
gdalwarp -of ECW test.tif test.ecw
Output driver `ECW' not recognised or does not support
direct output file creation.  The following format drivers are configured
and support direct output:
```

You should perhaps enhance you code and make it to print errors and warnings.

Comment: Thank you... then, what type of raster format can be accessed directly?

Comment: Formats which have "rw+" after the driver's name when you do `gdalinfo --formats` http://www.gdal.org/gdal_utilities.html.

Comment: Thank you, but actually I can only use the Text Editor in QGIS, not OsGeo4W, then, I am very limited in commands..That's why I haven't explore this yet. I will take a look !

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies with using `EPSG:3722`. When I use this CRS, the reproject algorithm runs successfully but does not produce an output.

Try changing this to another CRS and see if you get an output. If so then it means your code works and there's a problem with using `EPSG:3722`.

Comment: Do you mean the code number or the format (for example, using wkt... but I don't think it will work or will it?

Comment: @user64823 - The code number. Using wkt in the algorithm also works but doesn't seem to work with `3722`, I tested it with a couple of rasters.

Comment: It doesn't , I am using now "EPSG:4326" and doesn't work.  I am trying to reproyect a .tif now

Comment: @user64823 - Strange, works for me...

Comment: I have been using more types of EPSG.. just in case, but nothing works

Comment: @user64823 - Could you [edit](http://gis.stackexchange.com/posts/190112/edit) your question to include the full code please? You used `RasterLayer` in the algorithm but we can't see how it was defined =)

Comment: Could it be a problem of system environments? Unfortunately, I can't controll them,

Comment: It is already edited

Comment: Did you take seriously the backslash thing? https://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/

Comment: sorry, I haven't seen this comment until now. Do you mean to use "/" instead of "\" ? 

By the way, I am using TEXT EDITOR IN QGIS, is this a problem? (I mean, does it have less capabilities when executing scripts that the processing toolbox scripts?